# How do I repeat a function (x times, each time unique output)?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an app that will repeat a function X number of times. Each time, the function will generate a random number. Once it generates the code, the code would then create an array with the new random numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the code that create the random number and hyphenates it, but I'm having trouble calling the function cardNumber to repeat itself x number of times and put the results in an array.

```
function hyphenate($str) {
    return implode("-", str_split($str, 4));
}

function cardNumber() { 
    for ($s = '', $i = 0, $z = strlen($a = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')-1; $i != 2; $x =      rand(0,$z), $s .= $a{$x}, $i++);

    $uid = uniqid(true);
    $ccn = substr_replace($uid, $s, 0, 0);
    $upperccn = strtoupper($ccn);
    $editedccn = hyphenate($upperccn);
    return $editedccn;
};

$array = array(str_repeat(cardNumber(), 2));
var_dump ($array);
```

Comment: Are you searching for something like a...for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
$i = 0;
$times_to_run = 16;
$array = array();
while ($i++ < $times_to_run)
{
    $array[] = cardNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a more readable approach that's also easier to type

```
foreach(range(1,20) as $i) { 
   ...
}
```

Comment: right? easier to read? what if `$times_to_run` is 0? yeah... now your loop runs 2 times. That isnt very good

Answer (score 5):

```
$num = amount of times to execute
for($i =0; $i < $num; $i++){
    $array[] = cardNumber();
}
#then
var_dump($array);
```